# Rails - How to associate one product to multiple users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Beginner question here, any help much appreciated. I have a table of users and a table of products and a join table called products_users. I can successfully link a product to a user in the command line by doing this:

```
u = User.where(:state => 'Oregon').first
u.products << Product.where(:search_location => 'Portland')
```

My first question is how would I link the Portland product to ALL users that have the state of Oregon and not just one user? If I don't add the .first it doesn't work.

But my main question is how to get the app to do this instead of me doing it in the command line? For instance, I have a table that contains 10,000 users and 1000 of them are :state => 'Oregon' so how do I create an admin page where I can type Oregon into the state field and then type Portland into another field and the appropriate entries are linked together and added into the join table?

UPDATE

Using siddick's code I've come up with this:

admin.rb

```
def link_product_to_user
products = Product.where(:search_location => params[:location])
User.where(:state => params[:state]).find_each do |user|
  user.products << products
end
  end
```

admin_controller.rb

```
def index    
@link = link_product_to_user
end
```

admin/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :location %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :location %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :state %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :state %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

which gives the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `link_product_to_user' for #<AdminController:0x007fd8e899bf10>
```

How should I define the method so it can be found? And is using form_for(@link) the correct way to submit the values to the method? thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? There are a couple of ways to do this.

Comment: Also when you say 'type Oregon into a field', do you mean find Oregon users and then update all with state Portland?

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it. I'm at the beginner stage where if I see the code I'll understand what it all does but when faced with a blank page I haven't got a clue where to start

Comment: I mean find users who have state field called Oregon (the state column is in users table) and then link them to the product that has a search_location field called Portland (search_location is a field in the products table)

Comment: Do you need help with the search, update or both. S

Comment: need help with it all, siddick's answer looks good but will take me a while to figure out where everything goes, will be back online later

Comment: Don't panic about it, you're doing the right thing using the console to get the query first. Siddick's method looks good - just break it all down. Get the search working, then the insert, and then mould together. Good luck, let me know if you need more help and I can add an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_each` to process record one by one.

```
def your_action
  products = Product.where(:search_location => params[:location])
  User.where(:state => params[:state]).find_each do |user|
    user.products << products
  end if products.exists?
  ... Your code ...
end
```

Index View file can be:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => "link_product_to_user") do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :location %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :state %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :state, params[:state] %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hey that looks like what I'm looking for, I have to run now but will try it later and let you know, thanks

Comment: you're a star siddick,it worked right out of the box, thanks very much for your help